# Grab Object Propertys from NSMutableArray Objective - C VS C++

Tags: objective-c

Hey there I'm new to objective c is there any way to grab and objects properties once it's in an NSMutable array.

like this:

so in c++ it would look like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   someArray[i].someClass.somePropertyInTheClass;
}
```

is there any possible way to do that with an NSMutableArray in OBJECTIVE -C

Thanks in advance all you pro objective c-ers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways to loop through an array in Objective-C. First, using an index:

```
NSInteger count = [array count];

for (int i; i < count; i++)
{
    id object = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@", [object somePropertyInTheClass]);
}
```

Note that the the count is stored in a variable rather than in the for loop. This avoids having to recalculate the count each time through the loop.

A more concise method is with fast enumeration:

```
for (id object in array)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [object somePropertyInTheClass]);
}
```

Both versions are semantically equivalient, they both log each object's `somePropertyInTheClass` property in the array (assuming each object has a `somePropertyInTheClass` property). In both versions, `id` can, and should, be replaced with a specific class, eg `NSDictionary *` based on what you store in the array.

While fast enumeration is more concise, the approach with the counter is useful if you need to use the index for something other than accessing one array. Also, fast enumeration does not allow you to modify the array, *even in another method*, while looping. In most cases though, when iterating through an array, fast enumeration can be used.

Comment: fast enumeration gives you immutabe object ref

Comment: ??? It doesn't change anything about the objects you give it. If your array is filled with `NSMutableDictionary` objects, you'll get mutable dictionaries out. You cannot, however modify the array during the loop or that will cause an error.

Comment: exactly but using traditional iterator you can do so inside the loop

Comment: I have added that caveat to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Hey there I'm new to objective c is there any way to grab and objects
>   properties once it's in an NSMutable array.

The mere fact of being included in an array or other container doesn't prevent you from accessing the properties of an object. If the object you want is at index i, you can get the object simply:

```
Person *person = [arrayOfPeople objectAtIndex:i];
```

or even simpler:

```
Person *person = arrayOfPeople[i];
```

You can then of course get the property like this:

```
NSString *name = [person valueForKey:@"name"];
```

or just:

```
NSString *name = person.name;
```

However, your example shows a loop, suggesting that you might want to get the same property of all the objects in an array. Objective-C containers have the very nice property that they respond to `-valueForKey:` by getting the value for the given key from each contained object and returning a container with just those values. So, you can say:

```
NSArray *names = [arrayOfPeople valueForKey:@"name"];
```

and you get an array of names in `names`, with one name for each object in the array `arrayOfPeople`.

You can, of course, also iterate over the array:

```
for (Person *person in arrayOfPeople) {
    NSString *name = person.name;
    NSLog(@"The name is %@", name);
}
```

Finally, you should know that mutable arrays work just the same way as non-mutable arrays when it comes to accessing objects. The only difference between a mutable array and a non-mutable array is that you can add or remove objects from a mutable array after you create it. The mutability of the objects contained in the array isn't affected by the array's own mutability. That is, if you have an array `arrayOfPeople`, and if the `Person` objects stored in it can be modified, then you're free to change the name, age, etc. of any object stored in the array regardless of whether `arrayOfPeople` is mutable or non-mutable.

Comment: `arrayOfPeople.name` does not work because `NSArray` does not respond to the accessor's selector `name`. If you really have to, use `[arrayOfPeople valeForKey:@"name"]`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Good catch -- thanks. I don't think the "if you really have to" is warranted, though; this is reliable, documented behavior that does the job efficiently and with less code than you'd otherwise need to do the same thing.

Comment: Well, I'm not a friend of `valueForKey:` on containers. But I agree it's Apple's choice to do this, so here we are. I think it misdefines a very fundamental service (KVC). Example: Without knowing about the special override you would assume that `[@[] valueForKey:@"count"]` would return `@0`, at least that's what KVC guarantees. Yet it does return `@[]`. This is only one of the reasons for my dislike. On the other hand I accept that this train has left the station and I'm probably alone avoiding valueForKey on NSArray (along with dot notation for non-property access, ...)